# Where do I place the Open FIle Indicator in the program?

Tags: fortran

Now this simulates a 3 dimensional random walk, and its been adjusted to have 50 particles. It is not running in the system, so I am just wondering what is wrong with it. Anybody have any clue?

```
program RW3D

    implicit none

    open (1, file = ‘sarathi.txt’)

    integer, parameter : : n = 50
    integer : : x(50), y(50), z(50)
    integer : : i, j
    real : : P

    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    do i = 1, 100
    do j = 1, 50
       call random_number (p)

        write (1,*) i, x, y, z

         if (p .lt. 1.0/6) then
            x(j) = x(j) - 1
         else if (p .lt. 2.0/6) then
            y(j) = y(j) - 1
         else if (p .lt. 3.0/6) then
            z(j) = z(j) - 1
         else if (p .lt. 4.0/6) then
            x(j) = x(j) + 1
         else if (p .lt. 5.0/6) then
            y(j) = y(j) + 1
         else
            z(j) = z(j) + 1
        end if

    end do

end program RW3D
```

Answer (score 2):

"Here is my code, it doesn't work, please fix it" is not really very well looked upon here, as you can see by your score.

"It is not running" is terribly vague. A better description would be:

"Fails to compile with the error message:

```
RW3D.f90:7.12:

    integer, parameter : : n = 50
            1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

What am I doing wrong?"

There are many things wrong with your code:

1. An executable statement (`open (1, file = ‘sarathi.txt’)`) before the declaration block (all the `integer` and `real` declarations) is finished.
2. The file name is not opened with a proper `'` or `"` -- probably your text editor has replaced that one with *nicer looking* single quotes that don't work.
3. There shouldn't be a space between the two colons.
4. Each do loop needs its own `end do`
5. Please don't use file i/o unit numbers of less than 10. That's asking for trouble. Even better, use the `newunit` keyword:

Here's an example for the `newunit`

```
program hello
    implicit none
    integer :: my_unit
    open(newunit=my_unit, file='delme.txt', action='write')
    write(my_unit, *) "Hello World"
    close(my_unit)
end program hello
```

Try these, and you should get further.

Answer (score 1):

The `OPEN` statement can't be before declaration. Move it after the last declaration.

Careful also about `: :`, it should be `::`

And as said in a comment, there is an `end do` missing.